# When i add code to paintComponent() my gui disappears

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

In my code after i added code to `paintComponent()` when i run it, all the JLabel, textfields, and buttons disappear the textfields and buttons reappear when i click on them while the program is running but i still can't see any of the JLabels.
I hope it is something silly i have commented out the code in the `paintComponent()` method that seems to cause this error.

```
public class snowBoarding extends JFrame {
    private JButton getReset() {
        if (Reset == null) {
            Reset = new JButton();
            Reset.setBounds(new Rectangle(162, 411, 131, 39));
            Reset.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 18));
            Reset.setText("Reset");
            Reset.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e){
                    textField_1.setText("0");
                    textField_2.setText("0");
                    textField_3.setText("0");
                    textField_4.setText("0");
                    textField_5.setText("0");
                    textField_6.setText("0");
                    textField_7.setText("0");
                    textField_8.setText("0");
                    textField_9.setText("0");
                    textField_10.setText("0");
                    textField_11.setText("0");
                    textField.setText("0");
                    total_1.setText("0");
                    total_2.setText("0");
                    Overall.setText("0");
                    DrawPanel.clear(DrawPanel.getGraphics());                       
                    DrawPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));


                }
            });
        }
        return Reset;
    }


    public JButton getButton_calc_draw() {
        if (Button_calc_draw == null) {
            Button_calc_draw = new JButton();
            Button_calc_draw.setBounds(303, 411, 131, 39);
            Button_calc_draw.setFont(new Font ("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 18));
            Button_calc_draw.setText("Draw");
            Button_calc_draw.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    // Get values from the text fields
                    run_1[0] = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                    run_1[1] = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
                    run_1[2] = Integer.parseInt(textField_2.getText());
                    run_1[3] = Integer.parseInt(textField_3.getText());
                    run_1[4] = Integer.parseInt(textField_4.getText());
                    run_1[5] = Integer.parseInt(textField_5.getText());

                    for (int i = 0; i < run_1.length; i++) {
                        temp[i] = run_1[i];
                    }
                    Arrays.sort(temp);

                    for (int i = 1; i < (temp.length -1) ; i++){
                        avg1+=temp[i];
                    }

                    avg1 = avg1/4;


                    run_2[0] = Integer.parseInt(textField_6.getText());
                    run_2[1] = Integer.parseInt(textField_7.getText());
                    run_2[2] = Integer.parseInt(textField_8.getText());
                    run_2[3] = Integer.parseInt(textField_9.getText());
                    run_2[4] = Integer.parseInt(textField_10.getText());
                    run_2[5] = Integer.parseInt(textField_11.getText());

                    for (int i = 0; i < run_2.length; i++) {
                        temp[i] = run_2[i];
                    }
                    Arrays.sort(temp);

                    for (int i = 1; i < (temp.length -1) ; i++){
                        avg2+=temp[i];
                    }

                    avg2 = avg2/4;


                    if (avg1 > avg2){
                        OverallScore = avg1;
                    }
                    else {
                        OverallScore = avg2;
                    }


                    total_1.setText(Integer.toString(avg1));
                    total_2.setText(Integer.toString(avg2));
                    Overall.setText(Integer.toString(OverallScore));
                    DrawPanel.repaint();


                }
                // Transfer the image from the BufferedImage to the JPanel to make it visible.
                 ;
            });

        }
        return Button_calc_draw;
    }



                }
            });
        }
        return Reset;
    }


    private myJPanel getDrawPanel() {
        if (DrawPanel == null) {
            DrawPanel = new myJPanel();
            DrawPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            DrawPanel.setBounds(new Rectangle(258, 39, 326, 361));
            DrawPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
            DrawPanel.setEnabled(true);

            DrawPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));

            //Instantiate the BufferedImage object and give it the same width 
            // and height as that of the drawing area JPanel
            img = new BufferedImage(DrawPanel.getWidth(), 
                                    DrawPanel.getHeight(), 
                                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            //Get its graphics context. A graphics context of a particular object allows us to draw on it.
            g2dImg = (Graphics2D)img.getGraphics();

            //Draw a filled white coloured rectangle on the entire area to clear it.
            g2dImg.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
            g2dImg.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
        }
        return DrawPanel;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                snowBoarding thisClass = new snowBoarding();
                thisClass.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                thisClass.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public snowBoarding() { 
        super();        
        setResizable(false);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        initialize();   
    }

    private void initialize() {
        this.setSize(600, 500);
        this.setContentPane(getJContentPane());
        this.setTitle("Snowboarding Score Calculator");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

}

class myJPanel extends JPanel {

BufferedImage img;
Graphics2D g2dImg;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Rectangle2D.Double rectangle;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //Must be called to draw the JPanel control. 
     // As a side effect, it also clears it.
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 260-score[0] * 2, 25, score[0] * 2);
        g2D.setPaint(Color.blue); 
        g2D.fill(rectangle);
        g2D.draw(rectangle); 

}

 protected void clear(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);


     // Also clear the BufferedImage object by drawing a white coloured filled rectangle all over.
     g2dImg.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
     g2dImg.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));


}

}
```

edit: removing unnecessary code

i need the repaint to draw rectangles using the run_1 and the run_2 array as the x or y values after i click draw and the reset to return the painted image back to a white slate.

draw button --> draws the graph

reset button --> removes the graph so that a new graph can be created.

Comment: Are you calling a repaint method on each render?

Comment: Post just enough of your code to duplicate the issue, don't just dump everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shall not use `g2dImg` in `paintComponent()`, but `g` instead (the parameter received by method `paintComponent()`).  More precisely, `((Grpahics2D)g)` instead of `g2dImg`.

`g2dImg` doesn't seem to be initialized in your code posted here, maybe you have done it somewhere...

More generally, you shall always use the `Graphics` instance you received in paint methods (casting it to `Graphics2D` if needed). You shall not try to reuse/share/store instances of `Graphics`.

The same applies for the `clear()` method.

Here is an example of how to rewrite this `paintComponent()` method:

```
private boolean shallPaint = false;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (shallPaint) {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 260-score1 * 2, 25, score1 * 2);
        g2D.setPaint(Color.blue); 
        g2D.fill(rectangle);
        g2D.draw(rectangle);              
    }
}

public void setShallPaint(boolean pShallPaint) {
    shallPaint  = pShallPaint;
}
```

Then simply call `myJPanel.repaint()` to repaint it.

You shall replace, in your reset button:

```
DrawPanel.clear(DrawPanel.getGraphics());
```

with:

```
DrawPanel.setShallPaint(false);
DrawPanel.repaint();
```

And in `Button_calc_draw`:

```
DrawPanel.setShallPaint(true);
DrawPanel.repaint();
```

Comment: Could you please explain that simpler sorry. and provide a code edit.

Comment: See my completed answer for a detailed example.

Comment: Sorry but the g2dImg is used in the other class, what code do i use to clear it now the program starts with the bar there i want it to appear after i click the draw button.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand: what do you mean with "clear it", and "the bar"?

Comment: the rectangle appears as soon as the code is launched i want it to appear after i have clicked on the draw button which is when repaint() is called.

the clear method no longer works when it is called it doesn't clear the panel to blank white.

Comment: See my edit answer, I've added `if (shallPaint)`: you don't need the `clear()` method, because you can't literally clear a panel, you can only avoid painting it. So when the clear button is hit and when application starts, simply set this boolean variable `shallPaint` to `false` to avoid painting, then call `repaint()`. Of course, set it to `true` when you want your rectangle to be painted.

Comment: Also, for the next questions, please put some minimal code here, not all this quantity of code ;) You may need to re-work / edit your code so that we better understand your problem and your need.

Comment: It won't let me change the shallPaint boolean variable within the buttons is there a way to do this 'private static boolean shallPaint = false;' do i use this at the start of the other class to declare it and then change it within the buttons so that it applies to the repaint() call?

Comment: I can't really minimse the amount of code i am using since i am not 100% sure of the problem

Comment: Sorry I don't understand since I don't see how you have added `shallPaint` in your code... You need to minimize your code (and show us your `shallPaint`) so that it produces your issue but with fewer lines of code (see the downvotes on your question)

Comment: I tried to minimize the code. and displayed it before implementing the shallpaint edit.

Comment: thanks a lot lastly how would i use the data stored in the arrays 'run_1[]' and 'run_2[]' instead of 'score1'

Comment: Sorry but `score1` is not displayed anymore now that you have minimized code size. Which was expected since you shall ask one question for each issue, so you may need to ask a new question on StackOverflow with another minimized code (I can't answer you with this code)

Comment: with the code displayed sorry it would be the array 'score[]' i would like the data from the gathered from the draw button into the arrays 'run_1[]' and 'run_2' moved into the 'score[]' array

Comment: the arrays are currently public static